# How to switch "rows value" to "columns" in database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, excel-formula, vba

I use SQL Server 2008. Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT [CIExtendedAttributeID]
      ,[dbo].[CIExtendedAttribute].[CreatedBy]
      ,[dbo].[CIExtendedAttribute].[CreationDate]
      ,[dbo].[CIExtendedAttribute].[ModifiedBy]
      ,[dbo].[CIExtendedAttribute].[ModificationDate]
      ,[ConfigurationItemID]
      ,[Value]
      ,[dbo].[CIExtendedAttribute].[CIExtendedAttributeTypeID]
      ,[dbo].[CIExtendedAttributeType].DescrEN
  FROM [dbo].[CIExtendedAttribute]
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[CIExtendedAttributeType] ON [dbo].[CIExtendedAttribute].CIExtendedAttributeTypeID = [dbo].

[CIExtendedAttributeType].[CIExtendedAttributeTypeID]
```

```html
the result :

CIExtendedAttributeID CIExtendedAttributeTypeID          DescrEN                       VALUE
 0                              1                         MAC adress                  000B6XXXXX8
 1                              1                         ESN                         100B6XXXXX8
 2                              2                         Display                     19"
 3                              2                         MAC adress                  100B6XXXXX9


I would like :

TESTCIExtendedAttributeID  TESTCIExtendedAttributeTypeID    MAC adress      ESN            Display
 0                              1                           000B6XXXXX8     100B6XXXXX8    NULL                              
 2                              2                           100B6XXXXX9            NULL    19"
```

I would like to switch the rows value to columns. The example is very light but the reality is another thing. This may be in another table or anything else. I can export to Excel too.

### SQL Fiddle ##  [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cebdd/1).

Comment: is it through SSIS `Balanced Data Distributor`?

Comment: Create [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for your case from there we can drive, may be with pivot or xml approach

Comment: yes bdd is database (sorry It's french : base de données)

Comment: @VenkataPanga , I added SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cebdd/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good example in this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query) on how to do a SQL Pivot. The sample they provide is:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        year(invoiceDate) as [year],left(datename(month,invoicedate),3)as [month], 
    InvoiceAmount as Amount 
FROM Invoice
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount)
    FOR [month] IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, 
    may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
)AS pivot
```

I'll let you play around with it to get the final query you need for your complex scenario.